# How to work with HEX strings without native decimal/scientific interpretation?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am working with hexadecimal values in a workbook, and aside from having the numeric values taken as decimal numbers, some hex numbers are being perceived as scientific notation in for example the `TEXT()` function.

I'd love for this workbook to completely ignore any cleverness about interpreting numbers and treat all text as text. how can I achieve this?

```
0123 interpreted as decimal 123
7e01 interpreted as 70
```

The main challenge right now is that I need to invert the values in little/big endian for `HEX2DEC` to work correctly, but my function

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(TEXT(E97,"0000"),3,2),MID(TEXT(E97,"0000"),1,2))
```

is falling over on scientific notation, specifically the value `7e00`. Rather than producing `007e` I am getting `0700`. I am going to this trouble to ensure the leading zeroes are captured on the apparently decimal values, but the scientific is a whole new problem.

Comment: `Text()` appears to be for formatting numbers, which is why it is attempting to alter the output. maybe try `T()` (https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html)

Comment: Both of these act on the already "interpreted" value in the cell. As far as I known there is no way to get the true hex string back from e.g. '00e7'.

Answer (score 0):

Calc, just as Excel, has exactly that problem.

The only real remedy is to set the cells containing hex strings to "Text", *(CTRL+1, or 'Format cell')*
or enter the value prepended with `'` *="what follows is a literal text value"*

Sidenote:
**HEX2BIN()** in Excel has quirky a limitation at 10 bits in binary numbers (i.e. max value 1023),
and **Calc** seems to have a 9-bit/511-limit.

Comment: So, the downvote is for ...?

Comment: I hate when ppl downvote and don't even say why.  In addition.. not a bad answer.  I gave you the point back.